# Can't install CKeditor widget extension in yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions

My greetings to everyone. 
I have problem with vendor version. I have installed yii couple months ago, and now I am trying to put CKEditor Widget for Yii2 `https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget`
but I am getting error
The file or directory to be published does not exist: `/localdev/web/vc/dev2/tdms/vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor yii 2`
Could you please help?
I found that in vendor file there were added some new classes. 
Can I update vendor successfully?Or can I use vendor folder of the current yii 2 folder?

```
<?php use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditorInline;?>

<?php CKEditorInline::begin(['preset' => 'basic']);?>
    Test text
<?php CKEditorInline::end();?>
```

Comment: how did you installed the widget?

Comment: I have installed extension via composer.